# Manipulate data using numpy loadtxt

Tags: python, file-io, numpy

I have file which have data in the form

```
 Irend =
   292.62 
    256.3 
   175.82 
   166.34 

 IloadI =
        0              
   7.8987 
   7.1084 
    9.477
```

I am trying to read it through numpy.loadtxt and getting valueError

```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> np.loadtxt('data.txt')

  ValueError: could not convert string to float: Irend
```

Please help me to manipulate the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `skiprows` argument to ignore a given number of lines:

```
np.loadtxt('data.txt', skiprows=1)
```

but it will stuck again in `"IloadI"` in your case. You must parse this file before using `np.loadtxt`.

One suggestion is to use a list comprehension to remove the lines with `"I"`:

```
tmp = [i for i in open('data.txt') if not 'I' in i]
a = np.genfromtxt(tmp)
```

If you know how many if these entries you have (`'Irend'`, `'IloadI'` etc) you can reshape `a`:

```
a.reshape(2, -1).T
#array([[ 292.62  ,    0.    ],
#       [ 256.3   ,    7.8987],
#       [ 175.82  ,    7.1084],
#       [ 166.34  ,    9.477 ]])
```

to get something more usable...